# Piano playing matching pitch of spoken voice - is there a name for this?

Tags: piano, voice, pitch

This is my first post of the Music SE so apologies if this question isn't in the right place!

The other day, I was listening to a new album by electronic artist "Yimino" and I came across [this](https://yimino.bandcamp.com/track/uss-george-washington) (WARNING: EXPLICIT LANGUAGE) short track and wondered whether there is a name for the piano playing technique where the player seems to "imitate" his speaking voice through the pitch (is this the right word) of his piano playing?

I've tried various google search terms to try to find an answer but as I'm struggling to explain what it is I'm hearing, I've made no headway. It does seem like the sample is of some sort of performance artist, so it made me wonder if it's a known technique.

If anyone has come across something like this before - are there any more examples (video or audio) you could point me to?

Any help would be appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: For far more classy and mature simulations, listen to George Benson. Vox and guitar.

Answer (score 1):

Unison playing. Uni = one or as one, son = sound or note. Usually in the same octave, but I believe unison can be named when notes are an octave apart, played simultaneously. Sometimes everyone gets to play - as in Stevie Wonder's Sir Duke solo.